# Wait cursor not showing in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have found several questions related to how to show a wait cursor but I can't find any that are related specifically to IE10.  I have an application where I would like the wait cursor to show while I am fetching or updating data in a database via PHP.  I have tried several options, all of which work in Chrome, but none of which work in my IE10 testing (my audience is a small group so I can keep it to those two browsers, although I can't limit to only Chrome).  The current code that I am trying is the following.

CSS

```
body.wait .move {
    cursor: wait;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('body').addClass('wait');
    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('body').removeClass('wait');
    });
})
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Missing `$` in `(document).ajaxStart(function () {`

Comment: I added the missing $ to the code above. Looks to be a typo and not the bug since OP says it works in Chrome.

Comment: Did you move the cursor after the class was added, does the cursor redraw?

Comment: Are you sure that the cursor is over the element that's class is "move"? Change the css rule: remove the .move, what happens?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
(document).ajaxStart(function(){
$('body').addClass('wait');
});
```

To

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
$('body').addClass('wait');
});
```

Comment: If it is working in Chrome, this would just be a typo in the question.

Comment: I added the $ before (document) and that still did not work.  Perhaps if I describe what I am trying to do it will help. When the page is loaded (it's actually a page with tabs), several tables and charts are built using php calls to a SQL database.  Since that takes a few seconds, I would like to have a wait cursor.  Once they are built, I submit information with a Submit button of a form element, which also updates the database using php.  I would like to have a wait cursor at this time is well.  So, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the `cursor` property with jQuery and changing `ajaxStop` to `ajaxComplete`.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

And remove the CSS.

You can get the jQuery Migrate plugin [here](http://jquery.com/download/) to check if it's because of the version you are using.

Comment: Thanks Jacques.  Still works great with Chrome, no luck on IE 10.  Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('body').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).css({'cursor':'wait'})
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).css({'cursor':'default'})
});
```

Cursor changes on any ajax start and end. That includes `.load()`.